# Command to extract Linux source code in Yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am working on Yocto, and I added meta-intel layer to my bblayers.conf..

I need to make modifications to Linux source code, so I need to look at what all files are present..

Can you please provide the bitbake command to get the location of linux source code.

I tried `bitbake -c unpack linux-intel` and went to build/tmp/work/ and did not find source code..

Comment: ```bitbake linux-intel -c devshell``` will take you there

Comment: @rettichschnidi, just curious,  why bitbake -c unpack linux-intel didn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain components which are used as source for multiple recipes are extracted into a shared place as a build optimization and linux kernel is one of such components so you can run

```
bitbake -cshared_workdir virtual/kernel
```

then the sources will be in

```
 <TMPDIR>/work-shared/<MACHINE>/kernel-source
```

If you then want to modify sources then
there are couple of ways to do kernel development

1. [Devtool](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#using-devtool-to-patch-the-kernel)
2. [Tradition Kernel Development](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#using-traditional-kernel-development-to-patch-the-kernel)

Comment: Please notice that patches are not applied in `work-shared` while `devtool modify` apply patches automatically in `workspace`.  And links are broken.